# Fprintf consumes characters

Tags: c, file

My code is currently consuming characters of the output a log file and I don't know exactly why.

```
FILE* theLog;
char filename[150];
theLog = fopen(filename, "w");
fprintf(theLog, "Blah Blah Blah");
time_t t = time(NULL);
struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);
fprintf(theLog, " Time: %d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d\n", tm.tm_year + 1900, tm.tm_mon + 1, tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec);
fclose(theLog);



FILE* fp = fopen(((Start *)start)->logFile, "a");
fprintf(fp, "More Stuff");
fclose(fp);
```

My output would then be something like: "Blah Blah Blah Time: 2015-6-1 19:56:48 uff"

"More Stuff" gets consumed/overwritten/gone for some reason.

Comment: Are you sure you have your \0 at the end of your strings?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. Chances are the issue is related to something you haven't shown here. Showing a completely self-contained and compilable example that shows the issue would help.

Comment: See [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the help center.

Comment: (1) Your code is incomplete (as user3386109 and uesp point out – look up that MCVE!!), in particular you do not show us how `filename` and the exciting looking `((Start *)start)->logFile` are filled and defined respectively. (2) You do not write a newline after `"More Stuff"`, which _might_ confuse the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Code is truncating the file with

```
theLog = fopen(filename, "w");
// w truncate to zero length or create text file for writing
```

Use `"a"` to append.

```
theLog = fopen(filename, "a");
```